# tcolorbox: valign of lower part to the top

Tags: vertical-alignment, tcolorbox, alignment

I want the lower part right of the upper part.

Why don't I get top alignment for the lower part? 
`valign lower=top,  % <------   Problem here!`  
has no effect.

[image]

PS: Just for interessts: is there something special for a "lower part title"?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe=false,
margin=2cm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
enhanced, % 
boxrule=0pt,   frame hidden, % no Frame
%colframe=white,
colback=yellow!25,
arc=2pt, % "rounded corners"
%  halign=flush center,
% Title  =====================
colbacktitle=yellow!25,
coltitle=black, % Fontcolor Title
fonttitle=\bfseries\Large,
% Alignment  =====================
valign lower=top,  % <------   Problem here! 
#1, % eventually further optional keys
}

\tcbset{
splitten/.style={
% "Lower Part" =================
lower separated=false,% 
sidebyside, % Lower part to the right
},
}

\newcommand\TikzI{
\vbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\draw[] (0,0) rectangle (4,5) node[midway, rotate=45]{TikZ I};
\end{tikzpicture}  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}[title=Title:, splitten]
\TikzI
\tcblower
\textbf{Lower Part Title:}

aaa

bbb
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, use `sidebyside align=top` to set vertical alignment of a `tcolorbox` in side-by-side mode.

Second, use `tikz` option `baseline` (see `pgfmanual` v3.1.7a, sec 12.2.1) to set the baseline of `tikzpicture`. Here the baseline is set to one line (without line skip) lower than the upper edge of `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe=false,
  margin=2cm,
]{geometry}


\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{
  enhanced, % 
  boxrule=0pt,   frame hidden, % no Frame
  %colframe=white,
  colback=yellow!25,
  arc=2pt, % "rounded corners"
  %  halign=flush center,
  % Title  =====================
  colbacktitle=yellow!25,
  coltitle=black, % Fontcolor Title
  fonttitle=\bfseries\Large,
  % Alignment  =====================
  sidebyside align=top,
  #1, % eventually further optional keys
}

\tcbset{
splitten/.style={
% "Lower Part" =================
lower separated=false,% 
sidebyside, % Lower part to the right
},
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\TikzI{%
  \vbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={($ (current bounding box.north) + (0pt,-\f@size pt) $)}]
    \draw[] (0,0) rectangle (4,5) node[midway, rotate=45]{TikZ I};
  \end{tikzpicture}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}[title=Title:, splitten]
  \TikzI
  \tcblower
  \textbf{Lower Part Title:}
  
  aaa
  
  bbb
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]